# Linux sort numerically based on first column

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I'm trying to numerically sort a long list of csv file based on the number in the first column, using below command:

```
->  head -1 file.csv ; tail -n +2 file.csv | sort -t , -k1n
```

(I'm piping head/tail command to skip the first line of the file, as it's a header and contains string)
However, it doesn't return a fully sorted list. Half of it is sorted, the other half is like this:

```
9838,2361,8,947,2284
9842,2135,2,261,2511
9846,2710,1,176,2171
986,2689,32,123,2177
9888,2183,15,30,2790
989,2470,33,887,2345
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've also tried below with same result:

```
-> sort -k1n -t"," file.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tail -n +2 file.csv | sort -k1,2 -n -t","` should do the trick.

Comment: what does -k1,2 do as sopposed to -k1,1, or just even -k1?

Comment: If you omit the second value to `-k`, it uses the end of the line. In other words, `-k 1` specifies a sort field from field 1 to the end of the line.

Comment: so -k1,2 specifies sort field from column 1 to column 2, and -k1,1 specifies it as just column 1?

Comment: Yes - and `-k1,1` is actually more correct in your case, though `-k1,2` will produce the same result since there are no duplicates in the first column.

Answer (score 2):

To perform a *numeric sort* by the first column use the following approach:

```
tail -n +2 /file.csv | sort -n -t, -k1,1
```

The output:

```
986,2689,32,123,2177
989,2470,33,887,2345
9838,2361,8,947,2284
9842,2135,2,261,2511
9846,2710,1,176,2171
9888,2183,15,30,2790
```

---

> **-k** *pos1[,pos2]*
>
> ```
> Specify a sort field that consists of the part of the line between pos1 and pos2 
> (or the end of the line, if pos2 is omitted), inclusive.
> In its simplest form pos specifies a field number (starting with 1) ...
> ```